# What widget do you use to return a number of type int?

Tags: dart, flutter

I need to return an `int` from the `build()` method in a `StatelessWidget` class. `build()` method obviously returns a `Widget`. How can I convert my `int` to a `Widget`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Text will do

```
Text(42.toString())
```